# SQL accuracy for mappings

Tags: sql, database, hive, count, row

I join two tables if  they share a common id.

```
select *
from my_table m
join other_table o
on m.mid = o.oid
```

this gives me a new table I call new_table.  I choose a column (new_col) to get more information about it

```
select count(new_col)
from new_table
```

gives me 312. When I find distinct values however

```
select count( distinct new_col)
from new_table
```

I get 284.
If distinct count and regular count results are different, that means `other_table` had duplicate values for it's id. And during the join process, the duplicates matched to `mid` multiple times. I want to know how many ids from `mid` mapped to exactly one id in `oid` and  how many one-to-many matches there were, and then calculate the average of 1-1 mappings and many-1 mappings.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.  I'm not sure how you "make" a column unique when your query logic is specifying multiple values.  You haven't provided enough information to answer that.

Comment: I just fixed it. Hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to make some assumptions here as you haven't mentioned (in your tags) which database you are using (MySQL? PostgreSQL?, ??) and you don't state explicitly whether there can be duplicate ids in both tables (I infer that only other_table has duplicate ids).

So I made an example that looks like this:

```
.-----.-----.
| mid | oid |
:-----+-----:
|   1 |   1 |
:-----+-----:
|   2 |   2 |
:-----+-----:
|   3 |   3 |
:-----+-----:
|   3 |   3 |
:-----+-----:
|   4 |   4 |
:-----+-----:
|   4 |   4 |
:-----+-----:
|   4 |   4 |
:-----+-----:
|   5 |   5 |
'-----'-----'
```

and tested it with the SQL below:

```
WITH stats_base
     AS (SELECT mid, ocount
         FROM   my_table m
                JOIN (SELECT oid, COUNT(*) AS ocount
                      FROM   other_table
                      GROUP  BY oid) o
                  ON m.mid = o.oid)
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ocount = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_ones,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ocount = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS count_dups,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ocount = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.0 / COUNT(*) AS percent_ones
FROM   stats_base
```

and got this result:

```
.------------.------------.-----------------.
| count_ones | count_dups |  percent_ones   |
:------------+------------+-----------------:
|          3 |          2 | 60.000000000000 |
'------------'------------'-----------------'
```

which I believe is close to what you're after?

Comment: Yes, there are duplicates in both tables. Thank you! I will build on your code and try to solve it